# Has a no-ball call from the on-field umpire ever been overturned?

Tags: cricket, trivia, video-review

In Cricket, we come across so many instances in which a batsman gets called **out**, and then is changed to **not-out** because the replay shows the bowler bowled a **no-ball**. Has the inverse instance ever happened, where an on-field umpire signals no-ball and it is overturned after replay?

If yes, what happened to the Bowl bowled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot happen under the [ICC Playing Conditions](https://www.icc-cricket.com/about/cricket/rules-and-regulations/playing-conditions) as it would be incredibly unfair to the batsman. Imagine the scenario:

- Umpire calls "no ball".
- The batsman, hearing the call, goes for a big hit they wouldn't otherwise have done, as they know they cannot be dismissed.
- The batsman skies the ball and it is caught by the fielder.
- The fielding side appeal, and the batsman is out.

Comment: when decision is overtuned after replay because of no-ball, it is loss to Fielding Team :)

Comment: Yes, it's a loss. But the fielding team will not have changed their actions due to the call, so it's not unfair.

Comment: But, it will definitely affect the mentality of fielding team,if the wicket is of a good(set) player.:(

Comment: Seems like you could have a result such as 'ball is rebowled', no?